# Format array of data to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

I have a set of data that looks like

```
[
  {
    "title": "Appintment one",
    "allDay": false,
    "operators": [
      "600510d6d0ee8475bcb6de34"
    ],
    "start": "2021-01-25T14:48:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-01-28T14:48:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    "title": "Appintment two",
    "allDay": false,
    "operators": [
      "600510d6d0ee8475bcb6de34"
    ],
    "start": "2021-01-26T14:48:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-01-28T14:48:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    "title": "Appintment four",
    "allDay": false,
    "operators": [
      "600510d6d0ee8475bcb6de34"
    ],
    "start": "2021-01-26T14:48:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-01-26T14:48:00.000Z",
  }
]
```

This data is dynamic so I can have 1 or 100+ appointments. What I am trying to achieve is create an object where the key is the formatted `start` and the value is an array that contains the appointments for that day.

So for the above would be something  like

```
    {
25-01-2021: [
{
    "title": "Appintment one",
    "allDay": false,
    "operators": [
      "600510d6d0ee8475bcb6de34"
    ],
    "start": "2021-01-25T14:48:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-01-28T14:48:00.000Z",
  }],
26-01-2021: [
{
    "title": "Appintment two",
    "allDay": false,
    "operators": [
      "600510d6d0ee8475bcb6de34"
    ],
    "start": "2021-01-26T14:48:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-01-28T14:48:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    "title": "Appintment four",
    "allDay": false,
    "operators": [
      "600510d6d0ee8475bcb6de34"
    ],
    "start": "2021-01-26T14:48:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-01-26T14:48:00.000Z",
  }
]

}
```

So far I only manage to get the formatted date as key but the value is an object so it only contains one appointment per key...

My code (using moment):

```
data.reduce((acc,curr)=> 
                (acc[moment(curr.start).format('DD-MM-YYYY')]=curr,acc),{});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your data based on dates.

```js
const data = [ { "title": "Appintment one", "allDay": false, "operators": [ "600510d6d0ee8475bcb6de34" ], "start": "2021-01-25T14:48:00.000Z", "end": "2021-01-28T14:48:00.000Z", }, { "title": "Appintment two", "allDay": false, "operators": [ "600510d6d0ee8475bcb6de34"], "start": "2021-01-26T14:48:00.000Z", "end": "2021-01-28T14:48:00.000Z", }, { "title": "Appintment four", "allDay": false, "operators": [ "600510d6d0ee8475bcb6de34" ], "start": "2021-01-26T14:48:00.000Z", "end": "2021-01-26T14:48:00.000Z", } ],
      groupedByDate = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        const key = moment(o.start).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        r[key] = r[key] || [];
        r[key].push(o);
        return r;
      },{});
console.log(groupedByDate);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```